# Liquibase error with jhipster

Tags: postgresql, jhipster, liquibase

I am using jhipster to create entities. I created an entity called certificate with a foreign constraint. I deleted the constraint and the column referred to that constraint in the database and while trying to compile with maven clean install I got this error :

```
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2018-03-25 18:19:43.663  INFO 6936 --- [           main] f.d.pki.web.rest.CSRResourceIntTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-25 18:19:45.989  INFO 6936 --- [           main] f.d.pki.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Initializing Metrics Log reporting
2018-03-25 18:19:47.151 ERROR 6936 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster failed.  Error: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
2018-03-25 18:19:47.181  WARN 6936 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [fr/digitalberry/pki/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
2018-03-25 18:19:47.225 ERROR 6936 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [fr/digitalberry/pki/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:680)
    at org.h2.table.IndexColumn.mapColumns(IndexColumn.java:74)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:208)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:77)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:192)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:164)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 58 common frames omitted

2018-03-25 18:19:47.227 ERROR 6936 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7f2f5172] to prepare test instance [fr.digitalberry.pki.web.rest.CSRResourceIntTest@28be9a9d]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [fr/digitalberry/pki/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180316082939_added_entity_constraints_Certificate.xml::20180316082939-2::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "SIGN_ID" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.certificate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_certificate_sign_id FOREIGN KEY (sign_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.csr (id) [42122-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:680)
    at org.h2.table.IndexColumn.mapColumns(IndexColumn.java:74)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:208)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:77)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:192)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:164)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

who have an idea about how to solve that problem . and thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Any change to db schema must done via Liquibase changesets, avoid doing manual changes.
A changeset should be immutable, if you want to modify something create a new changeset don't modify an existing one.

Here, as you destroyed your h2 database with mvn clean, it just means that your last changeset is based on wrong assumptions about the database state.